# Proper method to restrict non logged users into certain pages

Tags: pages, actions, template-redirect

I was wondering which is the correct method to do this and which action hook should i use.

I have custom login/register pages so if the user try to go to a forbidden page and its not logged in i will redirect him to a login page.

Currently on my functions.php i got the following:

```
/*
*   Restrict non logged users to certain pages
*/

add_action('template_redirect','my_non_logged_redirect');
function my_non_logged_redirect()
{
     if ((is_page('mi-perfil') || is_page('agregar-empresa')) && !is_user_logged_in() )
    {
        wp_redirect( home_url() );
        die();
    }
}
```

Im using the right method/hook or should i use another one or a easier one?

Comment: Does your posted code work? If not, in what way does it not work, or work differently from what you expected?

Comment: it works fine. Just wanted to know if is proper way or i should use any other hook than template_redirect

Comment: "It works fine. Just wanted to know if is proper way or i should use any other hook than template_redirect" Close-voted as **not constructive**: "*As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.*"

Comment: So there is no way to ask if im doing things right?

Comment: Place your code as an answer. Reformat your question to ask how to accomplish this. The community can vote up/down your answer and other's possible solutions as well. This will give you the desired feedback within the scope of SE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldnt find a better method other than:

```
/*
*   Restrict non logged users to certain pages
*/

add_action('template_redirect','my_non_logged_redirect');
function my_non_logged_redirect()
{
     if ((is_page('mi-perfil') || is_page('agregar-empresa')) && !is_user_logged_in() )
    {
        wp_redirect( home_url() );
        die();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I just want to say thanks, I was able to use this and do exactly what I hoped changing the line to cover the category and sending people to my login page instead of the home url,

```
/*
*   Restrict non logged users to certain pages
*/

add_action('template_redirect','my_non_logged_redirect');
function my_non_logged_redirect()
{
     if ((in_category(1) && !is_user_logged_in() ))
    {
        wp_redirect( 'http://mysites.com/loginpage/' );
        die();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The posts/pages which you want to hide from non logged in users can be published as "Private" and it will not be available to any public visitor of the site. This way you don't need to implement any sort of redirection or custom code. 
You can find more information [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Content_Visibility#Private_Content).

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is almost a decade now, but I will just put it out there since I found it useful.

```
 /*
*   Restrict logged-out users from privileged pages
*/

add_action('template_redirect','rex_non_logged-in_redirect');
function rex_non_logged-in_redirect()
{
     if ((is_page('/*page id to be restricted*/') || is_page('/*page id to be restricted*/')) && !is_user_logged_in() ) /* Checks page(s) you want to restrict from logged-out users and also check if user is logged in*/
    {
        wp_redirect( 'enter the full url of your login page' );
        die();
    }
}
```

This is a leaf from what the guys have posted previously. Just wrapping it up together. I hope this helps anyone needing it.